# My C# multi-threaded console application seems to not be multithreaded

Tags: c#, multithreading, amazon-ec2

Here's my `C#` console program that uses Powerpoint to convert `ppt` files to folders of `png`s. This is supposed to be an automated process that runs on its own server.

I expect that as soon as a thread creates an image from a file, it should immediately remove the images and the source file.

The actual behavior is that, if five threads are running, it'll wait for five folders of images to be created before any thread can move any files. I'm able to see the images being created, and compare that with the `Console` readout, so I can see that a thread isn't trying to move the file.

Only after all the other threads have made their images, will any thread try to move the files. I suspect this is wrong.

This is an Amazon EC2 Medium instance, and it appears to max out the CPU, so five threads might be too much for this.

I also find that I can hardly use Windows Explorer while this program is running.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;

namespace converter
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int threadLimit=0;
        public static int currThreads = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inDir = args[0];
            var outDir = args[1]+"\\";
            var procDir = args[2]+"\\";
            Int32.TryParse(args[3],out threadLimit);
            Thread[] converterThreads = new Thread[threadLimit];
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(inDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".pptx") && !s.Contains("~$") || s.EndsWith(".ppt") && !s.Contains("~$"));
                var arrPaths = filePaths.ToArray();
                for(var i=0; i< arrPaths.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (currThreads < threadLimit && currThreads < arrPaths.Length)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("currThreads= " + currThreads + " paths found= " + arrPaths.Length);
                        try
                        {
                            var fileNameWithoutExtension = arrPaths[currThreads].Replace(inDir, "").Replace(".pptx", "").Replace(".ppt", "").Replace("\\", "");
                            var filenameWithExtension = arrPaths[currThreads].Substring(arrPaths[currThreads].LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                            var dir = arrPaths[currThreads].Replace(".pptx", "").Replace(".ppt", "");


                            Conversion con = new Conversion(arrPaths[currThreads], dir, outDir, procDir, filenameWithExtension, fileNameWithoutExtension);
                            converterThreads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(con.convertPpt));
                            converterThreads[i].Start();
                            Console.WriteLine(converterThreads[i].ManagedThreadId + " is converting " + fileNameWithoutExtension);

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Unable to convert {0} ", arrPaths[i]) + e);
                        }
                    }

                }
                for (var i = 0; i < converterThreads.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (converterThreads[i] != null)
                    {
                        if (!converterThreads[i].IsAlive)
                        {
                            converterThreads[i].Abort();
                            converterThreads[i].Join(1);
                            Console.WriteLine("thread " + converterThreads[i].ManagedThreadId + " finished, "+currThreads+" remaining");
                            converterThreads[i] = null;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (currThreads == 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("POWERPNT"))
                        {
                            proc.Kill();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e3)
                    {
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    class Logger{

        static void toLog(String msg)    
        {
                //TODO: log file    
        }

    }

    class Conversion{
        static int numberOfThreads=0;
        String input;
        String output;
        String outDir;
        String process;
        String nameWith;
        String nameWithout;
        int elapsedTime;
        System.Timers.Timer time;
        public Conversion(String input, String output, String outDir, String processDir, String nameWith, String nameWithout)
        {
            this.input = input;
            this.output = output;
            this.outDir = outDir;
            process = processDir;
            this.nameWith = nameWith;
            this.nameWithout = nameWithout;
            numberOfThreads++;
            Console.WriteLine("number of threads running: " + numberOfThreads);
            Program.currThreads = numberOfThreads;
            time = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            time.Start();
            time.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            elapsedTime = 0;
        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            elapsedTime++;

        }

        public void convertPpt()
        {

            var app = new PowerPoint.Application();
            var pres = app.Presentations;
            try
            {
                var file = pres.Open(input, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
                file.SaveAs(output, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPNG, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
                file.Close();
                app.Quit();
                Console.WriteLine("file converted " + input);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("convertPpt failed");
            }

            moveFile();
            moveDir();

        }
        public void moveFile()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("moving" + input);
            try
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("moving {0} to {1}", input, process + nameWith));
                if (File.Exists(process + nameWith))
                {
                    File.Replace(input, process + nameWith, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Move(input, process + nameWith);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Unable to move the file {0} ", input) + e);
                try
                {
                    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("POWERPNT"))
                    {
                        proc.Kill();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e3)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        public void moveDir()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("moving dir " + output);

            try
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("moving dir {0} to {1} ", output, outDir + nameWithout));

                if (Directory.Exists(outDir + nameWithout))
                {
                    Directory.Delete(outDir + nameWithout, true);
                }
                if (Directory.Exists(output))
                {
                    Directory.Move(output, outDir + nameWithout);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Unable to move the directory {0} ", output) + e);
                try
                {
                    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("POWERPNT"))
                    {
                        proc.Kill();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e3)
                {
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                numberOfThreads--;
                Program.currThreads = numberOfThreads;
                Console.WriteLine("took " + elapsedTime + "seconds");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FileSystemWatcher Class (System.IO).

Comment: @MartinJames: I was going to propose that, however I have had trouble with FileSystemWatcher misbehaving under some circumstances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every 1000ms you get a list of files in `inDir` and potentially start a thread to process each file.  You have very complex logic surrounding whether or not to start a new thread, and how to manage the lifetime of the thread.

The logic is too complex for me to spot the error without debugging the code.  However, I would propose an alternative.

Have a single thread watch for new files and place the file path into a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx) of files for processing. That thread does nothing else.

Have N additional threads that retrieve file paths from the `BlockingCollection` and process them.

This is known as a Producer / Consumer pattern and is ideal for what you are doing.

The example code at the bottom of the linked MSDN page shows an implementation example.

On a side note, you are catching and swallowing `Exception e3`.  Don't catch something you will not handle, it hides problems.

Comment: I would further propose using a `Timer` to search for new files, and using the `ThreadPool` (or `Tasks` If >= .Net 4.0) to run the conversion threads.